# Command line parameter inter c

Tags: c, integer

I want to make this program do the printing in `main()` only there are no command line arguments.
If there are command line arguments (which should just be one integer), it should run the function `bitcount()`.

How do I go about doing this? If there are no command line arguments I am not sure how this will work properly.

How would I check if the user put in a command line argument? And if they did, run `bitCount()` and not the `main()`. However if they do not put any command line integer argument, then it would just run main.

e.g `./bitCount 50` should call the `bitCount` function
but `./bitCount` should just run the `main`

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bitCount (unsigned int n);
int main ( int argc, char** argv) {

    printf(argv);
    int a=atoi(argv);

    //   int a = atoi(argv[1]);

    printf ("# 1-bits in base 2 representation of %u = %d, should be 0\n",
      0, bitCount (0));
    printf ("# 1-bits in base 2 representation of %u = %d, should be 1\n",
      1, bitCount (1));
    printf ("# 1-bits in base 2 representation of %u = %d, should be 16\n",
      2863311530u, bitCount (2863311530u));
    printf ("# 1-bits in base 2 representation of %u = %d, should be 1\n",
      536870912, bitCount (536870912));
    printf ("# 1-bits in base 2 representation of %u = %d, should be 32\n",
      4294967295u, bitCount (4294967295u));
    return 0;
  }

  int bitCount (unsigned int n) {
      //stuff here
  }
```

Comment: argc is the number of arguments, and argv is the argument array. So just check if `argc > 1` (first arg is the file name), and then access the value (first param) with `argv[1]`.

Comment: Really? You say you have **absolutely no idea** about how to do this? That's impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

argv is an array of strings that contains the program name followed by all arguments. argc is the size of the argv array. argc is always at least 1 for the program name.

If there was a paramter argc will be > 1.

So,

```
if (argc > 1)
{
    /* for simplicity ignore if more than one parameter passed, just use first */
    bitCount(atoi(argv[1]));
}
else
{
    /* do stuff in main */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int argc` contains the number of arguments in the command line, where the executable's name is argv[0].  So, `argc < 2` means that no command line parameters were given.  I don't really understand what you want or don't want to run in absence of command line parameters, but it should be behind a `if (argc < 2)`.

In your sample code you are doing a number of pretty odd things, with this in mind:

```
printf(argv);
```

as argv is a `char **`, or array of `char *` that's never going to produce anything useful.  Worse, as printf expects the format string as its first argument the line above can cause all kinds of weird things.

```
int a=atoi(argv);
```

same here.  atoi wants a string too, same issue as above.